# Settings value empty when main program not running

Tags: c#, visual-studio, application-settings

I have put my program settings values in a separate project called `Common` in my solution. I have a main project (let us call it `A`), and some other projects (`B` and `C`) and then one `Common` project. `Common` is added to `A`, `B` and `C`'s references. I have tried accessing `Common`'s settings value by using both:

1. Visual studio's `Settings.Setting` which is easy to use but tricky when it comes to reading from other projects.
2. A self-made `ini` file to read from and write to.

And now I realized they are both acting the same way and I think I am missing an important point. The setting values are accessible when the main project is running. When I update my settings, they are saved and it all works fine.

But sometimes I need to access these values from other projects while `A` is not running. In my case, project `B` is triggered by a Windows Service. It then reads the data from database and then executes the batch file. But it also needs to access `Common`'s settings. And they are empty strings!

So if we consider the 2nd approach above (reading from `ini`) `Common` has a value in its `Conf` static object (that I use to read and write the settings) called `ConnectionString`. This value is accessed in the main program by simply calling `Common.Conf.ConnectionString`. But when used by `B`, this value is empty. So I cannot access my Settings values.

What I might as well do, is to create a function that reads from the `ini` file every time I need these values and parse them once again as if the Common project does not exist.

But is there anything else I can do to make it work?

This is the code to my `Common`'s `Conf` sealed class that I use to read/write from the `ini` file.

```
namespace Common
{
    public sealed class Conf
    {
        public static string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        public static bool LoggerEnabled { get; set; }
        public static string FolderLocation { get; set; }
        public static string Delimeter { get; set; }

        static readonly string SETTINGS = "conf.ini";
        static readonly Conf instance = new Conf();
        Conf() { }
        static Conf()
        {
            string property = "";
            string[] settings = File.ReadAllLines(SETTINGS);
            foreach (string s in settings)
                try
                {
                    string[] split = s.Split(new char[] { ':' }, 2);
                    if (split.Length != 2)
                        continue;
                    property = split[0].Trim();
                    string value = split[1].Trim();
                    PropertyInfo propInfo = instance.GetType().GetProperty(property);
                    switch (propInfo.PropertyType.Name)
                    {
                        case "Int32":
                            propInfo.SetValue(null, Convert.ToInt32(value), null);
                            break;
                        case "String":
                            propInfo.SetValue(null, value, null);
                            break;
                        case "Boolean":
                            if (value == "1")
                                propInfo.SetValue(null, true, null);
                            else
                                propInfo.SetValue(null, false, null);
                            break;
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    throw new Exception("Invalid setting '" + property + "'");
                }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Save new configuration in conf.ini
        /// </summary>
        public static void SaveConf()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(Conf).GetProperties();
            Type myType = typeof(Conf);
            PropertyInfo[] propertyinfos = myType.GetProperties(
                   BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
            foreach (PropertyInfo p in propertyinfos)
            {
                if (p.GetValue(myType, null) == null)
                    sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}:{1}", p.Name, string.Empty));
                else
                    sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}:{1}", p.Name, p.GetValue(myType, null).ToString()));

            }
            string result = sb.ToString();
            File.WriteAllText(SETTINGS, String.Empty);
            File.WriteAllText(SETTINGS, result);
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: What I do is have a home-made settings object that I serialize and persist as an .xml file. Interfacing to reading (deserializing) and writing (serializing) the settings object is done by a coupld of methods in a common module. The settings object is a simple .Net class/object that can simply be passed around by reference.

Comment: @RenniePet Well the `Settings.Setting` is ultimately de/serialized into an `xml` file right? And I am already using the `ini` file using pretty much the same way except it is not `xml`.